# Avoid repeating letters between five simple programs

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, multiple-holes

Your challenge is to write 5 different full programs for the 5 following tasks:

1. Print `Hello, World!`.
2. Given an input on STDIN, output the factorial (you can assume that the input is an integer ≥ 0).
3. Given an integer N, calculate the sum of the primes ≤ N.
4. Given an input on STDIN, output the letters used in the input.
   For example: the input is `Hello world`, you need to output `helowrd`.
   Note that the output is in lowercase.
   You can assume that the input is always alphabetic with white spaces, the white spaces are ignored.
5. Output the following diamond exactly like this:

   ```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
    *****
     ***
      *
   ```

All these challenges are probably very easy, but there is a catch.
Every letter you use **cannot be used again** in the other programs.
This is not prohibited, but will give you a penalty of **+8 bytes**.
For example, if this is your program for the first task:

```c
print("Hello, World!");
```

Then you cannot use the following letters (in uppercase or lowercase form): `p`, `r`, `i`, `n`, `t`, `h`, `e`, `l`, `o`, `w`, `d` in the other programs.
If you do have to use them, you can “buy” each letter for 8 bytes.
So if you want to use the letter `l` again in another program, you receive a penalty of 8 bytes.
After you have paid the penalty, you can use each letter as many times as you want in *this* program.
Other characters don’t matter.
Also, all 5 programs should be in the same language.

This is a [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: This is a slightly different spin on challenges we've already had, but not different enough for it to not to be a multi-dupe in my eyes.

Comment: Does 8 bytes permit you to use a given letter as much as you like in the next program?

Comment: @Mego I'd vote to close this as a multi-duplicate without the restriction, but the restriction makes it a whole new game.

Comment: If you use a given letter in 3 programs, do you pay the 8 byte penalty twice (16 bytes)?

Comment: @trichoplax, yes you pay 16 bytes

Comment: @trichoplax Hardly. The existing solutions for the duped problems will still be competitive. The top solutions here will just be the concatenation of the duped questions' solutions, with a higher score from the penalty.

Comment: In TI-BASIC, there are tokens that *display* using certain letters (for example, `sin(` displays like `sin(`. However, they are not stored in memory that way (its token code is C2). Can we repeat the letters displayed without penalty?

Comment: Are we allowed to have trailing spaces on the lines of Task 5?

Comment: @ThomasKwa, the displayed letters don't matter, only the code matters. Also, trailing whitespaces are not allowed in task 5.

Comment: @Mego although the existing solutions will be competitive at first, I would expect variations tailored to the new restriction to win eventually. I can't tell in advance though.

Comment: There just aren't enough versions of `Print`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CJam, 73 bytes

```
"Obkkh+'Phukc&"7f^
q~m!
ri){'j3+_3++~},:+
lS-el_&
4{_' *4@-Y*('**+}%_1>W%\+N*
```

Each line is a full program. Try them online: [1](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22Obkkh%2B'Phukc%26%227f%5E) | [2](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~m!&input=10) | [3](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri)%7B'j3%2B_3%2B%2B~%7D%2C%3A%2B&input=5) | [4](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=lS-el_%26&input=Hello%20world) | [5](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=4%7B_'%20*4%40-Y*('**%2B%7D%25_1%3EW%25%5C%2BN*)

#### Letter map

```
 bc  f h  k   op    u       18
            m   q            4
        ij       r          17
    e      l      s          7
             n        w y   27
```

If you want (and each of your programs fits in a line), you can use [this CJam program](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B_el'%7B%2C97%3E%5Cf%7B%26Se%7C%7DS%40%2Cs3Se%5BN%7D%2F&input=%22Obkkh%2B'Phukc%26%227f%5E%0Aq~m!%0Ari)%7B109c_3%2B%2B~%7D%2C%3A%2B%0AlS-el_%26%0A4%7B_'%20*4%40-Y*('**%2B%7D%25_1%3EW%25%5C%2BN*) to create a letter map for your own submission.

Comment: Proof that osascript wasn't built for this: Your _entire submission_ is less than 2 of my programs. XD +1, nice job.

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, 90 bytes

First attempt...

#### Task 1: 20 bytes

```
+"Hello, "+C87"orld!
```

#### Task 2, 3 bytes

```
.!Q
```

#### Task 3, 9 bytes

```
sf}TPTSvz
```

#### Task 4, 6+8=14 bytes

```
@G{rw0
```

#### Task 5, 44 bytes

```
"   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

Answer (score 3):

## osascript, 759 Bytes

I knew this was going to be a lot when I started. o-o

**Task 1: 15 Bytes**

```
"Hello, World!"
```

I knew that it was going to be bad from this point.

**Task 2: 64 + 8*4 = 96 Bytes**

```
on run a
set o to 1
repeat a
set o to a*o
set a to a-1
end
o
end
```

Oh gawd.

**Task 3: 170 + 8*13 = 274 Bytes**

```
on run a
set o to 0
set t to false
repeat with i from 2 to a
set t to true
repeat with c from 2 to i-1
if i mod c=0 then set t to false
end
if t then set o to o+i
end
end
```

Dennis ≠ outgolfed.

**Task 4: 225 + 8*13 = 329**

```
on run a
set o to""
repeat with i in items of a
repeat with c in characters of i
if c is not in o then
if ASCII number of c<91 then
set o to o&(ASCII character of(ASCII number of c+32))
else
set o to o&c
end
end
end
end
o
end
```

...

**Task 5: 45 Bytes**

```
"   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *"
```

So, yeah. I knew I was gonna lose from the start. But it was interesting, I'd be interested to know if there's a way to do this in fewer characters. Character map (as provided by Dennis):

```
   de  h   l  o  r    w     15
a cdef hi  lmnop rstu w    160
a  de        nop rstu       57
abcdef hi  lmnop rstu w    214
                            39
                             0
```

The character count above is slightly off - newlines made it have issues, as the newlines were uncounted.

NOTE: The reason for not using stuff like `a's characters` or the like is that the `'` character has to be used when executing from the osascript command line. If I had used `'`, I'd have to use `\'` or something similar, which wouldn't have helped me at all. Also, it only recognizes `"` as string capturers, so I was kinda screwed there as well. But that was fun.

Answer (score 2):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 83 bytes, no characters repeated between programs

The five programs separated by newlines:

```
"Olssv'^vysk("7-

P

µf«äµL1=×S

32|ÍÌM64á<F¥

»   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

online interpreter:
[1](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=Ik9sc3N2J152eXNrKCI3LQ)
[2](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=UA==&in=NQ==)
[3](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=tWar5LVMMT3XUw==&in=MTA=)
[4](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=MzJ8zcxNNjThPEal&in=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkIg==)
[5](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=uyAgICoKICAqKioKICoqKioqCioqKioqKioKICoqKioqCiAgKioqCiAgICo=)

*The letters in problem 4 are printed in alphabetical order instead of the order they appear in, I did not find any rule against that*

### Explanation

```
"Olssv'^vysk("7- ; Hello World! shifted by 7 to avoid space

P ; product over the 1-based range to the input

µf«äµL1=×S
µf«         ; replace the numbers in the range 1 : input with their prime-factorisation
   äµL1=×   ; only keep the elements with a length of one
         S  ; sum up the array

; assumes that the input consists of ASCII letters and white-spaces 
32|ÍÌM64á<F¥
32|          ; or with 32 -> converts uppercase ascii to lowercase
   ÍÌ        ; get a list of all unique elements
     M64á<F¥ ; print the elements that are larger that 64 (filters out white spaces)
     M       ; for all elements
      64á<   ; is the the number greater than 64
          F  ; repeat that many times
           ¥ ; print

; string-literal containing the required output
; all possibilities to loop are used up by the previous answers
»   *      
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

Answer (score 1):

## NARS2000 APL, 144 bytes (85 characters)

### Task 1, 21 bytes (17 characters)

```
⎕←"Hello, World!"
```

### Task 2, 10 bytes (4 characters)

```
⎕←!⎕
```

### Task 3, 22 bytes (11 characters)

```
⎕←+/¯2π⍳2π⎕
```

### Task 4, 53 bytes (29 characters)

```
⎕←∪Q[26∣Q⍸⍞∩Q←⎕AV[97+⍳26]∪⎕A]
```

### Task 5, 38 bytes (24 characters)

```
⎕←" *"[1+4<∘.+⍨(⍳3),⊖⍳4]
```

Comment: Are those actually full programs? I don't know NARS2000 (and it's not available on my platform), but all dialects I know require assigning to `⎕` to print outside a REPL.

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, forgot I was fiddling inside the REPL.

Comment: You're not allowed to output trailing spaces for the diamond.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 46 bytes (non-competing)

```
“3ḅaė;œ»
Ɠ!
ÆRS
ɠQḲŒl
4Ḷ¤‘+¤ṖṚṭ×”*Fµ4Ḷṭ4ḶṚṖ¤F×⁶+⁸Y
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net) (Copy/paste each snippet)

Apparently, the restriction did not restrict golfing :) Just suggestions for the last one, of course, please.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, 398 bytes

I don't know why I decided to try this.

`-rprime` flag loads the `Prime` library for task 3. As per [the meta post on program flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/52194), adding flags treats it as a "different language", so I can't add `-n` or `-p` for some tasks and remove it for others, even if it would save bytes. (Tasks 1 and 5 take no input, and no input means programs with those flags won't run, which is why they can't be used.)

#### Task 1, 47 bytes

Backslash-escaped almost every letter to free letters up for usage in later tasks. `$>` is an alias for `STDOUT`, which will be used later.

```ruby
$><<"H\x65\154\154\x6f\54\40W\x6f\x72\154\x64!"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7IKlpSVpuhY39VXsbGyUPGIqzExjDE1NwLjCLC0GSJkYhIOZFeZGUGETRSWINqjuBVAaAA)

#### Task 2, 31 bytes

`3+9+~9 == 2` to avoid reusing `2`.

```ruby
p((3+9+~9..gets.to_i).inject:*)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7IKlpSVpuhb7CzQ0jLUttess9fTSU0uK9Ury4zM19TLzslKTS6y0NCGqoIoXLDSFMAA)

#### Task 3, 28 bytes + 56 (`().ceis`) = 84

Since this is the only task that doesn't say to take input from STDIN, this one is a lambda instead so I don't need to take a huge penalty from doing things with `gets.to_i` or something similar. This is probably the only time where `lambda` saves bytes over its stabby syntax `->`, which has to buy back `>` and uses up the `-` needed in Task 4.

```ruby
lambda{|e|Prime.each(e).sum}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7KI026WlJWm6FntyEnOTUhKra1JrAkBSeqmJyRkaqZp6xaW5tRAlywsU0qJNDWIhvAULIDQA)

#### Task 4, 67 bytes + 96 (`*.<achinrstu`) = 163

This one had wayyyyyy too much overlap but it was needed to do the given task. Uses `t,=*STDIN` to get the line of input, assuming newlines won't be present. Let me know if that's an incorrect assumption.

```ruby
t,=*STDIN;t=t.tr'A-Z','a-z';t=t.tr'^a-z','';STDOUT<<t.chars.uniq*''
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7IKlpSVpuhY3nUt0bLWCQ1w8_axLbEv0SorUHXWj1HXUE3Wr1GEicSCOjrq6NVCdf2iIjU2JXnJGYlGxXmleZqGWujrEKKiJC1Z7pObk5CuU5xflpECEAA)

#### Task 5, 53 bytes + 20 (`$*<>`) = 73

Buys back virtually every character in the program, since it's still cheaper than any alternative I could think of. Uses heredoc syntax for the string since we no longer have `'` or `"` and we're buying back `<` anyways since it's cheaper than buying back `puts`.

```ruby
$><<<<Q
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
Q
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7IKlpSVpuhY3TVXsbIAgkEtBQUELSGhpAUktEODSggAYFyoHUhYI0Qw1YwGUBgA)